# Laravel csrf-token mismatch

Tags: laravel, csrf

**Problem**. When I follow an simple authentication tutorial for Laravel (v.5.2), and tries to register a new user I get the error: CSRF-token mismatch.

I am quite new to Laravel, and I am not sure how to proceed.

**Background**. I crated a new project for the tutorial, and runs it on my local machine (windows 10, on port 8000). I run it with Composer and artisan. My database are also on my local machine with XAMPP (on port 10080).

**Code**. https://github.com/isak-glans/laravel_problem

**The tutorial:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k89EOb9fqa0&list=PL_UnIDIwT95PiPV641VBnEwFAvswNZKuX&index=11

Comment: You should probably refrain from using random tutorials on youtube. Laravel endorses laracasts.com quite explicitly, and there is a tutorial on setting up the `php artisan make:auth` authentication in the https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch tutorials see [episode 13](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/13)

Comment: "works on my machine" ;-) (OS X). Can you install it on another machine/vm? Maybe a windows problem?

Comment: Yep, thats right machine :) I am stuck with Windows I am afraid.
Jonathan - thanks for the link. I will check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a cross site request forgery field to your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

or use the helper method:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

This is used to prevent CSRF attacks.

Sorry didn't check your code first.

I cloned the app and registered without problems. I think that you are getting that error because the token expired.

Checkout this thread:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/csrf-token-mismatch-error-on-session-timeout-form/

Comment: He has one in the login form if you checked his code

Comment: Thanks. When I deleted the session cookie the problem disappeared. Hm, maybe the problem comes when I switch between different project, or something.